# Gathering information about the Reflective Optical Sensor CNY70

Tags: sensor, datasheet

As I was trying to gather information in the CNY70 datasheet (http://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf) I could not find the following information:
-Transfer function
-Operating range/Dynamic Range
-Resolution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find theses information because they do not make sense in the intended usage of the product.

For instance, a Bode diagram of a transfer function only makes sens for a linear system. Here the sensor characteristics are not linear at all.

The resolution (smallest increment you are able to measure) does not make any sense either. This is an analog sensor: there are no steps.

The "resolution" will depend on your acquisition system parameters, such as :

- number of bits of your ADC
- Signal processing ( averaging several measurements )
- etc

For similar reasons, the dynamic range is also related to your complete acquisition system. But all the characteristics of the transistor are given in this datasheet. Using them in the model of your complete acquisition system would allow you to have an estimate of your system performances.

But if a the end you don't find exactly the data you need, the solution is always the same: *real world testing*

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to create a Transfer Function for this based on 2% current gain @  0.3mm and some inverse square law for distance then another inverse power law for  missing the aperture window from the angle of reflection and another factor for reflection coefficient, then another for stray light and another for system noise.

The dynamic range for current is clearly similar to any good transistor but must considering the gain of 2% and max input current is limited, the range is very limited.

The general application for this is to detect a reflective object going by at a fixed distance in this range so the transfer function of the reflectivity of the object present or not is what must be the key factor and using worst case tolerances for a fixed threshold.

Obviously with any comparator design just as in logic, there must be tolerances for input Vol  and Voh or black and white in the Infrared band.

Keep in mind reflective black paint and even some matte black will look white or grey to Infrared and the pigment must be something like carbon based to absorb 900 nm or reflect it with white.

Thus after deciding how to optimize the mechanical design to 0.3 mm and regulate the input current , one  can then focus the design on material reflectance ratio so that a fixed threshold signal to noise ratio for black and white may be >  10:1 at all times to ensure low error rate just like data is measured by SNR and BER.

If the gap size is a problem, or you wish to linearize the gap to output level, forget it, because it of the inverse square laws with distance greater than some minimum gap.

**So Transfer Function is not the proper method here, unless you have good reasons to make this linear for a servo system.**  Then you better change your question to include these specifications.  Also include aging effects of LED and stray incandescent or sunlight.

If you wanted to use IR reflective sensors for say a different gap like 1 cm, then acustom design with custom small apertures is possible as we did in mid 90’s to detector a rotating power meter disk with a black sharpie stripe added